# Using p4merge as git diff tool

Tags: git, bash, version-control, windows-7, p4merge

I use `windows 7`. I want to use `p4merge` as Git diff/merge tool. I follow [this article](https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/git-for-window-tip-use-p4merge-as-mergetool/) and [this one](http://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/using-perforce-p4merge-as-diff-tool-for-git/) to setup and config `p4merge`:

```
git config --global merge.tool p4merge
git config --global mergetool.p4merge.path "C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe"
git config --global diff.tool p4merge
git config --global difftool.p4merge.path "C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe"
```

And these lines are from `git config`:

```
merge.tool=p4merge
mergetool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
diff.tool=p4merge
difftool.p4merge.path=C:/Program Files/Perforce/p4merge.exe
mergetool.keeptemporaries=false
mergetool.prompt=false
```

Now `git mergetool` command works fine. But when I use `git difftool` command in `git bash`, I expect `p4merge` but I see  internal implementation of diff in `git bash`.

I tried [Smooth Git + P4merge](http://pempek.net/articles/2014/04/18/git-p4merge/) but it does not work for me also I tried to do as described in [External Merge and Diff Tools](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#External-Merge-and-Diff-Tools) but I did not understand that.

**Note:**

When type of conflict is `removed file conflict`, `git difftool` command opens `p4merge`.

Comment: Replace `diff.tool=p4diff` by `diff.tool=p4merge`

Comment: @topheman Please see my edit.

Comment: Use `/` instead of `\\` as separator perhaps solve the problem...

Comment: @Philippe I tried that, but did not solve problem. I edit question,please see it again.

Comment: I also used the [instructions](http://pempek.net/articles/2014/04/18/git-p4merge/) and work with P4Merge successfully for changed files since quite a while using `git difftool --staged`. One thing annoys me though: the error message when files were added. p4merge wants files to compare. Is there a way to omit added files? How did you solve this?

Comment: Hi guys! Did you find the correct way for your issue ? I am in similar situation :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure if helps, but recent versions of Git support P4Merge (I use `git version 2.17.0.` on Windows through MSYS2).

You can tell if this is the case or not by running `git difftool --tool-help`. It'll list the available tools Git can use (because they've found them in your `%PATH%`) and the tools it *could* use (if they were installed).

If `p4merge` is in this list then you just need to add the path where `p4merge.exe` resides to your `%PATH%` (on Windows I recommend [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com) for this).

After this is done you just need the following config to be in your `.gitconfig`

```
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
```

and nothing else. So remove other stuff like `difftool.path` and all that.

Then just use `git difftool` or `git mergetool` to your hearts content.

**Note**: I had a repository in which even if I did issue the `git difftool` or `git mergetool` commands P4Merge wouldn't start. I'm not sure what was the problem in that repo. However I tried creating an empty repo somewhere on my drive with `git init`, add a file, commit it, then modify it, *then* I tried `difftool` and it worked. So if the above description doesn't work for you chances the problem lies somewhere else. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never :)

mergetool.p4merge.path should be mergetool.p4merge.cmd

Change path to cmd for both the mergetool and difftool lines.

Comment: You can use the option `mergetool.p4merge.path`, there will be a standard order of tabs: REMOTE, BASE, LOCAL.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac don't forget to add `/` before Applications as in:

```
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = /Applications/p4merge.app/Contents/MacOS/p4merge
```

This was why P4Merge wouldn't open for me when I ran below:

```
git mergetool
```

Answer (score 0):

[DeviantDev](https://www.deviantdev.com/journal/setup-p4merge-as-mergediff-tool) has a pretty good answer for this.

Adding this to my .gitconfig worked for me...

```
[diff]
    tool = p4merge
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "p4merge"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
[merge]
    tool = p4merge
[mergetool "p4merge"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Perforce\\p4merge.exe
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
```